# Mysql 4 join problems

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have two tables like that

```
table 1
cd_art  ct          rez
001ms   7933.00     0
001ms   0.00        0
001ms   10994.00    0


table 2
cd_art  an_ct   an2_ct
001ms   12.00   7
001ms   0.00    7
```

I want a result like that:

```
cd_art  ct          an_ct   an2_ct
001ms   18927.00    12      14
```

Thanks!

I already try with inner join but the result is not ok

```
SELECT t1.cd_art, 
sum(t1.ct) as ct, 
sum(t2.an_ct) as an_ct, 
sum(t2.an2_ct) as an2_ct
FROM table_1 t1 
INNER JOIN table_2 t2 
on t1.cd_art = t2.cd_art 
GROUP BY t1.cd_art

result:
cd_art  ct          an_ct   an2_ct
001ms   37854.00    36.00   42.00
```

Comment: is it an_ct a SUM of table2 column as well?

Comment: Come on. Try something.

Comment: Show us some effort from your side. We're not supposed to do your work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are multiplicating the lines by doing an inner join like that (3 lines table1 * 2 lines table2 = 6 lines). When doing sql query allways check first your join are correct before formatting your results (sum + group by) then you will have seen you had 6 lines of result.
So to resolve your problem, first sum the value on each table then join them :

```
SELECT t1.cd_art, t1.ct, t2.an_ct, t2.an2_ct
FROM (SELECT cd_art, sum(ct) as ct FROM table1 GROUP BY cd_art) t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT cd_art, sum(an_ct) as an_ct, sum(an2_ct) as an2_ct 
             FROM table2 GROUP BY cd_art) t2 ON t2.cd_art = t1.cd_art;
```

Comment: what do you mean 'subquery' doesn't work? what is your version of mysql?

Comment: It seems to be a limitation with mysql engine for versions under 4.1, so in pure sql getting this result might be tricky. Can you do two requests (the subqueries I wrote) then link them with your programming language outside the database? Can you create temporary tables with the subquery then make a request joinning them?

Comment: I think the only solution is with temporary table, but i tried to avoid that, because i use two temporary table for create table1 and table2, and now i need to create two more, and i think that will slow my execution....

Comment: Actually temporary tables will accelerate requests on high volumes if you use primary key/index. But if perfs are really important, then you should think about simply upgrading your mysql engine.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select t.cd_art,sum(t.ct),sum(t.an_ct),sum(t.an2_ct) from(
SELECT
    t1.cd_art ,
    t1.ct as ct,
    0 as an_ct,
    0 as an2_ct
FROM
    table1 t1
UNION ALL
SELECT
t2.cd_art,
    0 as ct,
    t2.an_ct as an_ct,
    t2.an2_ct as an2_ct 
FROM
    table2 t2
) t
group by t.cd_art
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7cb0/6)**

Comment: I already try this, but the result is not ok, the sum of ct, an_ct and an2_ct is (37854.00 36.00 42.00)

Comment: @AlexBasa:- Updated my answer. Please check now

Comment: @AlexBasa:- This works. [SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7cb0/6) And what do you mean by subquery doesnt work?